# HTTP APIs enable you to create RESTful APIs with lower latency and lower cost than REST APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, cloud, aws-api-gateway

I am reading AWS API gateway documentation.
There is a sentence confusing me

> HTTP APIs enable you to create RESTful APIs with lower latency and lower cost than REST APIs.

[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-overview-developer-experience.html#:%7E:text=HTTP%20APIs%20enable%20you%20to%20create%20RESTful%20APIs%20with%20lower%20latency%20and%20lower%20cost%20than%20REST%20APIs.) is the link to the page containing this sentence

What is the difference between RESTful and REST here? Because in many places I read that it's the same

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway offers multiple modes for using it

- [HTTP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html)
- [REST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html)
- [Websockets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html)

These are all capabilities that API gateway offers. What they are saying it that if you want to develop a REST service it is better to use the HTTP options instead of the REST one.

Most likely they will suggest to use lambdas and maybe dynamodb and go down a serverless routes, but that's not mandatory.